# How to delay the drop down menu for my website

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, delay

I have a small problem with the drop down menu on my site. (http://tornaia.com) When the mouse is just outside the menu, the menu dissapears, and I have to go back to the top. This can be a bit annoying when the menu has 3 or 4 levels. Is ther some way to put a delay on the menu so it doesn't go away at once?

Thanks you!

(Some time ago I tried to solve this issue in the Wordpress Forum, but we never made it. Anyway here is a link, so you can see what solutions we tried: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-delay-the-drop-down-menu-1?replies=10)

------EDIT (I inculde what I have tried here):-------------------

I found this file: wp-content --> themes --> rumput-hijau --> js --> methods.js

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){

    /* Reponsive videos */
    $j(".content-right").fitVids();

    /* Reponsive menus */
    $j(".nav").mobileMenu();

   /* Drop down menus */


    $j(".inside-primary-nav ul li ul").parent().addClass("arrow");

    $j(".inside-primary-nav ul li").hover(function(){

        $j(this).addClass("hover");

       $j(this).find("ul:first").slideToggle("fast");

    }, function(){

        $j(this).removeClass("hover");
        $j(this).find("ul:first").slideUp("fast");

    });

});
```

So I tried changing the last line to

```
$j(this).find("ul:first").delay('900').slideUp("fast");
```

but that messed up the menu. Then I tried this

```
/* Drop down menus */
$j(".inside-primary-nav ul li ul").parent().addClass("arrow");
$j(".inside-primary-nav ul li").hover(function(){
    $j(this).addClass("hover");
    $j(this).find("ul:first").slideDown("slow");
}, function(){
    $j(this).removeClass("hover");
    $j(this).find("ul:first").slideUp("slow");
});
```

This code makes the menu slow down when it slides down, but the menu doesn't remain any longer when your mouse goes of it. So it's not what am looking for. I would like that the menu remains like one second (or something) after you leave it with the mouse. In that way, if you leave it without intension, it wont go away, and you can continue. So then I tried

```
$j(".inside-primary-nav ul li ul").parent().addClass("arrow");
$j(".inside-primary-nav ul li").hover(function(){
    $j(this).addClass("hover");
    $j(this).find("ul:first").slideDown("slow");
}, function(){
    $j(this).removeClass("hover");
    setTimeout(function() {
    $j(this).find("ul:first").slideUp("slow");
    }, 1000);
});
```

This code made the menu drop down slow the first time you hover it. The second time you hover it it seems like it has already been opened, so it just pops up. But the slide up dosen't change. When I take the mouse of the menu, it still dissapears.

----------------- EDIT: In the first code in the question I inserted the whole code of the file, not only the "/* Drop down menus */"-part

Comment: You should include *here* in your Question ([edit]) the things you tried and the current code of your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var hoverTimeout = null;

$j(".inside-primary-nav ul li").hover(function(){
    $j(this).addClass("hover");
    $j(this).find("ul:first").stop().slideDown("slow");
    if(hoverTimeout){
        clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
    }
}, function(){
    $j(this).removeClass("hover");
    hoverTimeout= setTimeout(function() {
        $j(this).find("ul:first").stop().slideUp("slow");
    }, 1000);
});
```

**UPDATE**

Ok so I think I finally got this to work, it was more complicated than I thought but I believe i found a solution, it may not be the best implementation but here it goes:

First you need to update your themes CSS file located in `http://tornaia.com/wp-content/themes/rumput-hijau/style.css`, you have to replace all instances of `li:hover` with `li.hover`, this will make the sub-menus stay in position when the cursor is away from them.

Once that's done, update `methods.js`, replace the current hover handler with this one:

```
var hoverTimeouts = {}; //Obj to store timeouts
$j(".inside-primary-nav ul li").hover(function(){
    //Clear timeout if present
    if(hoverTimeouts[$j(this).attr('id')]){
        clearTimeout(hoverTimeouts[$j(this).attr('id')]);
        delete hoverTimeouts[$j(this).attr('id')];
    }else{
        //Show sub-menu
        $j(this).find(".sub-menu:first").hide().slideDown("slow"); 
    }
    $j(this).addClass("hover");
    //Hide all other sub-menus in the level and clear their timeouts
    $j(this).siblings().each(function(){
        if(hoverTimeouts[$j(this).attr('id')]){
            clearTimeout(hoverTimeouts[$j(this).attr('id')]);
            delete hoverTimeouts[$j(this).attr('id')];
        }
        $j(this).removeClass('hover').find('.sub-menu').hide();
   });
},function(){
    //if item has sub-menu
    if($j(this).find('.sub-menu').length){
        //Store reference to menu item
        var that = $j(this);
        //Set timeout to remove after 1 sec and add it to obj
        hoverTimeouts[$j(this).attr('id')]= setTimeout(function() {
            that.removeClass("hover");
            delete hoverTimeouts[that.attr('id')];
        }, 1000);
    }else{
        //no sub-menu so just remove hover style
        $j(this).removeClass('hover');
    }
});
```

Note: Don't remove anything else from `methods.js`, the last time the arrows disappeared because you probably remove the line where the class `arrow` is added.

**UPDATE 2**

I think I found a cleaner solution, you still need to modify the CSS as I explained before, then you can add this to a new `.js` file and include it in your site after `methods.js`, no need to modify it

```
$(function(){
    var hoverTimeout = null;
    $j(".inside-primary-nav ul li").unbind();
    $j(".inside-primary-nav ul li").hover(function(){
        $j(this).siblings().each(function(){
            $j(this).removeClass('hover').find('.sub-menu').hide();
            $j(this).find('.hover').removeClass('hover');
        });
        $j(this).addClass("hover");
        //Make sure parent style is ready to show new sub-menu
        $j(this).closest('.sub-menu').css('overflow','visible'); 
        $j(this).find(".sub-menu:first").stop().slideDown("fast");
   }, function(){
       if($j(this).find('.sub-menu:visible').length  === 0)
           $j(this).removeClass("hover");
   });

   $j(".inside-primary-nav > ul > li").hover(function(){
       if(hoverTimeout){
           clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
       }
   },function(){
       if($j(this).find('.sub-menu:visible').length > 0){
           var that = $j(this);
           hoverTimeout= setTimeout(function() {
               that.removeClass('hover').find('.sub-menu').hide();
               that.find('.hover').removeClass('hover');
           }, 1000);
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi koala_dev! Thanks for the answer. I tried it, but it didn't work. Your code made the menu open (or drop down) slow, but once I took the mouse of it, the menu dissapears just like before. This code for some reason also takes away the arrows in the menu that helps indicate where there are sub-menus. Anyway, thanks for trying. :)

Comment: EDIT: In the first code in the question I inserted the whole code of the file, not only the "/* Drop down menus */"-part

Comment: Hi again! I edited the style.css - file like you said. I created the new .js file (I called it delaymenu.js) and I put it in the same folder as methods.js. So far the menu is behaving just the same as before. How do I include the new file on my site? I have always just edited the files that are already there, so I'm not sure how to this (sorry, I know I'm a nood :p )

Comment: Edit `footer.php` in your themes folder, I think there you'll find the line that includes `methods.js` so copy and paste it below just change the file name to `delaymenu.js`

Comment: Hi, I didn't find `methods.js` in the `footer.php`, so I went searching for it (Cntl-F in every php file :p).. I found `methods.js` only one place, in  
`themes --> rumput-hijau --> includes --> enqueue.php`, <br/>and it was like:  
`wp_enqueue_script( 'rumputhijau-methods', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/methods.js', array('jquery'), '20120615', true );`..  
So Then I tried (mayby a bit randomly) to add:  
`wp_enqueue_script( 'rumputhijau-delaymenu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/delaymenu.js', array('jquery'), '20120615', true );`,  but again - no change at my site.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to make it better looking with linebreaks, but I can't seem to get the linebreaks working.. Hope you manage to read it anyway :)

Comment: I see, that didn't work because you would need to have a function `rumputhijau-delaymenu` defined as  a handler... I guess the simpler thing would be to update `methods.js`, remove the hover binding and replace it with the code I provided without the `$(function{})` wrap so the file will look like this `...addClass("arrow");var hoverTimeout = null;$j(".inside-primary-nav ul li").unbind();...`

Comment: Been reading on script queuing, try putting this just after methods.js is queued: `wp_register_script( 'delaymenu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/delaymenu.js',array('jquery'),'20120615',true );  
wp_enqueue_script( 'delaymenu' ); `

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if I understand what you ask me to do in your last comment. Anyway, I got it working now I think, so I guess I don't need it! =D I did what you said and put your "Update 2" - code in `methods.js`. Here is a link the new `methods.js`, so you can see what I did (http://pastebin.com/qRnfN4ZK). The only thing I changed from your code was `slideDown("slow");` to `slideDown("fast");`. So thanks a lot! It seems to be working great (at least in Firefox, my site has an issue with IE - but I'm working on it)..  Anyway thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hmm.. I just played a bit around with the menu to see if everything works, and there is a little bug.. Some of the sub menus won't open when hovering their arrow. And it's not always the same sub menus that don't work.. I mean: it was one that wouldn't open so I refreshed the site and then it started working.. But then it was another submenu that didn't open.. Any clue why this happens?

Comment: I tested in latest Chrome beta and everything seemed ok. What browser version are you testing on?

Comment: Hi. I use Firefox 22.0.. But it doesn't happen every time.. I just tried again, and I had to refresh the site like 6 times before I found the bug again.. And as I said it comes in different sub-menus every time.. strange..

Comment: I think I found the issue, add this to your CSS: `.sub-menu {overflow: visible!important;}`

Comment: Also I made a slight update to the JavaScript code just to remove the hover class when changing menu items

Comment: That seems to be working (at least so far).. But a small problem is that it takes away some of the smoothness in the drop-down. The sub-menus pops up instead of open up.. (this is of course not the biggest problem in the world :p )

Comment: I didn't see yor last comment before now, I'll try to update the code then.

Comment: No your're right that CSS is not the right fix, do update the code but let me think of another fix for the sub-menus not opening

Comment: Man, you're a genius! Thank you very much! I refreshed the site like 10 times, and everything seems to be working! So again, thank you! Btw, a link to the newest version of `methods.js`: (http://pastebin.com/iX1WLd2A)